# How to make it possible for bottle selection in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, radio-button

In My Application i have View like this image:

[image]

Now, I want to make such coading that, the one bottle should be selected.
if i select another bottle then that bottle should be selected and another bottle should be deselected. 
It should be happend for all the bottle.

I know that i can make it using the RadioGroup and RadioButton for Bottle.

but instead of that is there any other way to make it possible ?
If Yes, then please give me that technique.

Comment: why you go with complex thing when you do this things with radio button?

Comment: I think it is possible to achieve with custom gallery view

Comment: You can try GridView... Recommended is RadioGroup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice example (an inspiration):
http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/

```
onCreate(){
GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.phoneimagegrid);
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        imagegrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this,
                        "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
...
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                        // attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(120, 120));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(30, 8, 30, 8);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            return imageView;
        }

        // references to our images
        private Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.icon, R.drawable.icon,
                R.drawable.icon, R.drawable.icon, R.drawable.icon,
                R.drawable.icon, R.drawable.icon, R.drawable.icon };
    }
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/phoneimagegrid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="120dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nice One Example. Let me try it.

Comment: Nice Example here. But i want to see the button/image should be remain selected till i pressed another button/image.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer do you just need an imitating effect of buttons or buttons themselves?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manual. Put all buttons in a array and in the onclick listener select it and deselect all the others in the array.

Hope this helps...